# How to pass data from UI Alert Controller to another view controller iOS

Tags: ios, mobile

Im working on scanning attendance app. a bit confuse on how to open another view controller through alert view.

This is my code:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController (title: "Please Confirm Before Scan", message: messageToShow, preferredStyle: .alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "Proceed to Scan", style: .default, handler: {action in

picker.sourceType = .camera

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction (title: "Reselect", style: .cancel, handler: nil);},

actionSheet.addAction(FourthViewController),

actionSheet.addAction(canPerformAction),

present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

)}
```

I want my UI alert view when i click **"proceed to scan"** and go to another *FourthViewController*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController (title: "Please Confirm Before Scan", message: "messageToShow", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed to Scan", style: .default) { (action) in
    gotoFouthViewController(/*add argument if needed*/)
}
let cancelaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Reselect", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    //cancel the alert
}
actionSheet.addAction(okaction),
actionSheet.addAction(cancelaction),
present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

// somewhere in the present controller add this

```
func gotoFouthViewController(argument) {
  //push or present the fourth view controller here
}
```

Comment: the second column "Somewhere in the present controller" is it FourthViewController? Sorry im a bit confuse on that part :)

Comment: No it is the controller where the action sheet is shown.

Comment: @fnsmp Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your view hierarchy.

Lets say you want to push a view controller on the alert action on to the navigation stack of the presenting view controller. Inside the action you will have to write the code for the dismiss of the `UIAlertController` and then you can push the *FourthViewController* onto the navigation stack or if you want to present the *FourthViewController*, then just simply present it.

```
//inside the view controller presenting the alert
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yo", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
       alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       //push or whatever by referencing self
    }
}))
```